# Dividing by all combinations of a variable grouped by factor in R

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, combinations, division

My data looks like this:

```
set <- rep(c(1,2,3,4), each = 15)
h_density <- rep(c(1,3,6), each =5 )
n_density <- rep(c(100,500,1000,5000,10000), times =4 )
counts <- runif(60,900,10000)
data <- data.frame(set,h_density,n_density,counts)
data$set <- as.factor(data$set)
data$n_density <- as.factor(data$n_density)
data$h_density <- as.factor(data$h_density)
```

Within a given set there are three levels of `h_densities` 1,3,6 and five level of `n_densities` 100,500,1000,5000,1000. For a given set and given `h_density`, I want to divide all possible combinations of `counts` of lower to higher density. So, I want to divide the counts associated with n_densities `100/500, 100/1000, 100/5000, 100/10000, 500/1000, 500/5000, 500/10000, 1000/5000, 1000/10000, 5000/10000`. For the output I want to print the set, h_density, print ratio of of n_densities, count of ratio of n_densities

For example, the result for the first few rows should look like:

```
 set h_density n_density_ratio count_ratio
  1   1        100/500         <value>          
  1   1        100/1000        <value>    
  1   1        100/5000        <value>    
  1   1        100/10000       <value>      
  1   1        500/1000        <value>      
  1   1        500/5000        <value>     
 ...
```

How can I achieve this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data isn't too large, it is good and simple to make all combination by `inner_join()` and filter it by inequality of `n_density`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  inner_join(data, by = c("set", "h_density"), suffix = c(".l", ".r")) %>% 
  filter(as.numeric(n_density.l) < as.numeric(n_density.r)) %>% 
  mutate(n_density_ratio = paste0(n_density.l , "/", n_density.r))
```